# Showing that $d(x,y) = \mbox{min}\{1,|x-y|\}$ is a metric

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

I need to show that

$$d(x,y) = \mbox{min}\{1,|x-y|\}$$

is a metric. I started proving that

$$d(x,y)\ge 0$$

because $|x-y|$ is a metric, so $|x-y|\ge 0$ and that $1\ge 0$.

Now, we know that $x=y\implies |x-y|=0$ and $0$ is the $\mbox{min}$ of $\{1,0\}$, so $x=y\implies d(x,y) = 0$. Now if $d(x,y) = 0$ we have that $\mbox{min}\{1,|x-y|\}=0\implies |x-y|=0\implies x = y$ because $||$ is a metric.

Also, since $|x-y| = |-y+x| = |-(y-x)| = |y-x|$, we have that the sets $\mbox{min}\{1,|x-y|\}$ and $\mbox{min}\{1,|y-x|\}$ are equal, and therefore $d(x,y) = d(y,x)$

Now, to demonstrate that the triangule inequality holds, I could only think about the following reasoning: I started breaking it down in a lots of cases. For example:

$$1\le 1+1$$

$$1\le 1+|x-z|$$

$$1\le |x-y|+1$$

$$\cdots$$
$$|x-z|\le |x-y|+|y-z|$$

so

$$d(x,z) \le d(x,y) + d(y,z)$$

am I right? Does somebody has a better idea? I'm asking this because later I'll have to prove it for the following metric:

$$d''(z,z') = \mbox{max}\{d_k(x_i, x_i'), i\in \{1,\cdots,n\},k\in \{1,\cdots,n\}\}$$

where $d_k$ are metrics.

then I'll get a lot of cases to prove.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If either $|x - y| \ge 1$ or $|y - z| \ge 1$, say $|x - y| \ge 1$, then

$$d(x,z) \le 1 = d(x,y) \le d(x,y) + d(y,z).$$

If, on the other hand, $|x - y| < 1$ and $|y - z| < 1$, then

$$d(x,z) \le |x - z| \le |x - y| + |y - z| = d(x,y) + d(y,z).$$

Comment: why do you say that $d(x,z) \le 1 $?

Comment: @Guerlando it's true, because by definition, $d(x,z)$ is the smaller of the numbers $1$, $|x-z|$.